# How many simultaneous visitors Craft CMS can handle?

Tags: craft3, performance, hosting

I am looking for a CMS as a backbone for front-end work and I like CraftCMS by its interface and structure, so I wonder if CraftCMS is capable for this project. In practice, most of the work will be done on front-end, but next to pageloads, there will be some Ajax requests to the server too and also will users need to log in.

Is Craft CMS (v3) realistically capable of handling around 10.000 logged in visitors simultaneously? I don't know all the details about the project yet, but is there something to say about this so far? Is it critical in CraftCMS? Or should it handle these amounts just fine? As 10.000 simultaneous users on the website looks like a lot to me.

Also, do you guys perhaps know what to look for in hosting specs in order to allow these amounts of simultaneous visitors to all have performant experience (both pageloads and ajax)?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It's unlikely that Craft CMS would be the limitation here, but rather the devops architecture and overall technical architecture (static cache, etc.)

Comment: I'm not a devop. Do you have some information on specs the webhosting needs to have in order to make this work with great performance? Can you say something about this with this (little, I know) information? How do I know what hosting party/package could serve this need? And what to look for?

Answer (score 1):

> Is CraftCMS (v3) realistically capable of handling around 10.000 logged in visitors simultaneously?

Generally speaking, yes. Depending on the specifics of the site and what the users are doing, you might have to make some environmental accommodations.

As always with stuff like this, so much of it depends on things like the hosting architecture (load balancers, web servers, hardware specs, session/cache storage, caching) as well as Craft's information architecture, template logic, plugins, caching, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Brad Bell. I'm not really a devOp nor do I have ambition to develop in that direction. But I was hoping there would be some rough guideline requirements to check on hosting services out there for these amounts of visitors. Guess it's not that easy to answer like I would have hoped. But it's nice to know at least it's not limited right out of the box ;)

Comment: BTW, You edited the texts in my post? Huh?